# Basic calculus, derivative of function with two variables

Tags: calculus

This is my function:

$$e^{x^2 y - 2x^2 - y^2}$$

Here is my solution: imgur.com/a/IV2GS imgur.com/a/UKjQq imgur.com/a/iDFjX

I need to find the stationary points to it and classify them.

I have came this far, got the stationary points and even $f''(x,y)$ of my function, just need to put in the stationary points into the second derivative and see if they are max or min or saddle point.

Can someone please help me with the last step of classifying the stationary points? My brain has stopped worked due to exhaustion.

Comment: I suggest you to do a break then.

Comment: I must hand it in tomorrow, and I really have to go to sleep. I won't be able to do it tomorrow. Please help me? I am truly desperate

Answer (score 1):

You have done all of the hard work. From your calculations, we have:

$$\Delta(x, y) = f_{xx}(x, y) f_{yy}(x, y) -(f_{xy}(x, y))^2$$

Where:

- $f_{xx}(x, y) = e^{x^2 y-2 x^2-y^2} (2 x y-4 x)^2+(2 y-4) e^{x^2 y-2 x^2-y^2}$
- $f_{yy}(x, y) = e^{x^2 y-2 x^2-y^2} \left(x^2-2 y\right)^2-2 e^{x^2 y-2 x^2-y^2}$
- $f_{xy}(x, y) = 2 x e^{x^2 y-2 x^2-y^2}+e^{x^2 y-2 x^2-y^2} (2 x y-4 x) \left(x^2-2 y\right)$

We will use these [*notes*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/RelativeExtrema.aspx) to guide our classification.

- For $(0,0)$, we have $\Delta(0,0) = 8, f_{xx}(0,0) = -4$
- For $(-2, 2)$, we have  $\Delta(-2,2) = -\dfrac{16}{e^8}, f_{xx}(-2,2) = 0$
- For $(2, 2)$, we have  $\Delta(2,2) = -\dfrac{16}{e^8}, f_{xx}(-2,2) = 0$

Comment: Thank you so much, is (0,0) our minimum point, (-2,2) and (2,2) saddle point?

Comment: Did you look at the blue box in the link?